# How to replace the wrong spelt word with the correct one in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, str-replace, text-mining

I know similar question might have asked but I feel my requirement is peculiar.
I have two data frames: one with wrongly spelt words and another data frame with corrected words.

I need to replace each incorrect word with the correct word in another data frame.
Could you please let me know if there is any best possible way.

```
a <- data.frame(reported_terms=c('abdome pain','adominal ache','adomen'),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

b <- data.frame(wrong=c('adomen','adominal','abdome'),correct=c('abdomen','abdominal','abdomen'),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I am trying with the following code but not getting the expected output

```
corr_report_terms=list() # created empty list.

for(i in a){
  str_split(i," ")
  if(any(i %in% b))
    corr_report_terms <- b$correct
}
```

Expected output:

```
abdomen pain
abdominal ache
abdomen
```

Answer (score 1):

Tricky but works:

```
library(stringi) 
stri_replace_all_regex(a$reported_terms, "\\b"%s+%b$wrong%s+%"\\b", b$correct, vectorize_all=FALSE)
```

```
[1] "abdomen pain"   "abdominal ache" "abdomen"
```